# Create multiple dfs from a single df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as:

```
Company Sales
A        100
A        200
A        300
B        50
B        60
C        10
C        20
```

Now I want to make separate dfs for each of the company such that one df only contains info on one company as below:

```
Company   Sales
A        100
A        200
A        300
```

Similarly, for B as -

```
Company   Sales
B        50
B        60
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use `groupby` in Pandas and save individual dataframe in excel (or any other format). Here is the working code.

```
df_grp = df.groupby('Company')

for comp_nam, comp_grp in df_grp:
    file_name = comp_nam.upper()+".xlsx"
    comp_grp.to_excel(file_name, index=False)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a tonne :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `groupby` and transform to dictionary:

```
dfs = dict(list(df.groupby('Company')))
```

then you can access the sub-dataframes by key:

```
>>> dfs['A']
  Company  Sales
0       A    100
1       A    200
2       A    300
```

#### how to do something with the dataframes programmatically:

```
for company, data in df.groupby('Company'):
    emailing_function(company, data)
```

or:

```
companies = df['Company'].unique()
dfs = dict(list(df.groupby('Company')))

### other part of code
for company in companies:
    emailing_function(company, dfs[company])
```

Comment: Thanks Mozway... but I have >1000 records like this and I want to create dfs for each of the company and mail them their respective records as attachments. I cannot manually enter dfs['A'] for each company and extract dfs. Is there a way to run a loop to extract all separate dfs individually.

Comment: I strongly discourage you to do this, especially if you need to do something programmatically. You do not need to type anything manually, let me add a update to the answer

Comment: Use a for loop or get company names with `df.keys()`.